# How to upload image to cloudinary and specify the limit for the image size and a custom destination folder in the cloudinary with nestjs

Tags: image, upload, nestjs, cloudinary

I want to upload image to cloudinary in nestjs. I want to limit the size of the image users can upload to, say, 1 MB.

I also want to upload the image to the folder I created in my cloudinary media library.

How do I achieve this in my Nestjs app?.

This is my current implementation.

cloudinary.provider.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { v2 } from 'cloudinary';
import { CLOUDINARY } from './constants';

export const CloudinaryProvider = {
  provide: CLOUDINARY,
  useFactory: () => {
    return v2.config({
      cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME,
      api_key: process.env.API_KEY,
      api_secret: process.env.API_SECRET,
    });
  },
};
```

cloudinary.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UploadApiErrorResponse, UploadApiResponse, v2 } from 'cloudinary';
import toStream = require('buffer-to-stream');

@Injectable()
export class CloudinaryService {
  async uploadImage(
    fileName: Express.Multer.File,
  ): Promise<UploadApiResponse | UploadApiErrorResponse> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const upload = v2.uploader.upload_stream((error, result) => {
        if (error) return reject(error);
        resolve(result);
      });
      toStream(fileName.buffer).pipe(upload);
    });
  }
}
```

profile.service.ts

```
  async uploadProfileImage(fileName: Express.Multer.File, id: string) {
    try {
      const uploadImage = await this.cloudinaryService.uploadImage(fileName);
      const updateProfileImage = await this.userModel
        .findByIdAndUpdate(
          id,
          { $set: { profileImage: uploadImage.url } },
          { new: true },
        )
        .exec();

      if (!updateProfileImage) {
        throw new NotFoundException('User not found');
      }
      return {
        updateProfileImage,
        message: 'Profile image uploaded successfully',
      };
    } catch (error) {
      throw new BadRequestException(error.message);
    }
  }
```

the logic is working fine but I want to add logic that will allow me to specify destination folder and limit image size.

Comment: For the folder, you can add some the `folder` upload parameters as documented [here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload_optional_parameters:~:text=following%20characters%3A%20%3F%20%26%20%23%20%5C%20%25%20%3C%20%3E%20%2B-,folder,-String).
For the 1MB logic, you'll need to check the size of the file and check if it is under 1MB or not

Answer (score 0):

I found solution

cloudinary.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UploadApiErrorResponse, UploadApiResponse, v2 } from 'cloudinary';
import toStream = require('buffer-to-stream');

@Injectable()
export class CloudinaryService {
  async uploadImage(
    filename: Express.Multer.File,
  ): Promise<UploadApiResponse | UploadApiErrorResponse> {
    // Check if the size of the file is more than 1M
    if (filename.size > 1000000) {
      throw new Error('Please upload a file size not more than 1M');
    }
    // Check if the file is an image
    if (!filename.mimetype.startsWith('image')) {
      throw new Error('Sorry, this file is not an image, please try again');
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const upload = v2.uploader.upload_stream(
        { folder: 'profileImage' },
        (error, result) => {
          if (error) return reject(error);
          resolve(result);
        },
      );
      toStream(filename.buffer).pipe(upload);
    });
  }
```

1. To specify a limit for the image size use this

   if (filename.size > 1000000) {
   throw new Error('Please upload a file size not more than 1M');
   }

in this example if the image size is more than 1MB error will be thrown

2. To specficy a destination custom folder in the cloudinary Media Library use this

   const upload = v2.uploader.upload_stream(
   { folder: 'profileImage' },
   (error, result) => {
   if (error) return reject(error);
   resolve(result);
   },
   );

In this example, the image will be uploaded to a folder named "profileImage" in the cloudinary media library.

Comment: Users find it difficult to understand code only answers with no explanation. Please consider adding some description explaining how it solves the problem or add comments in the source code at appropriate places.

Comment: Ok, noted I will update the answer